# React native drawer not opening on swipe over map

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps, react-native-navigation

I am using [react-native-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation) to start a single screen app that contains a Google map using - [react-native-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps) and a left drawer:

Navigation:

```
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
        screen: {
            screen : 'map.MapScreen',
            title : 'Map',
            navigatorStyle: {
                navBarHidden: true
            }
        },
        drawer : {
            left : {
                screen : 'drawer.DrawerScreen',
                passProps: {}
            },
            disableOpenGesture: true
        },
        animationType: 'slide-down',
        passProps: {}
    })
```

MapScreen:

```
export default class MapScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}>
                </MapView>
            </View>
        )
    }



}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        zIndex: -1
    },
    map: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
});
```

Unfortunately if I try to open the drawer, by swiping to the right, over the map, it won't open.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use an overlay to add some invisible edge on the side of the map that does capture the gesture for opening the drawer.
looks something like this:

```
const Screen = {
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
};
class Foo extends React.Component<Props, object> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.mapContainer}
        />
        <View style={styles.mapDrawerOverlay} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  mapContainer: {
    width: Screen.width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
  mapDrawerOverlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    opacity: 0.0,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: 10,
  },
});
```

This will use an overlay that is transparent and covers a small fraction of the map view. Beginning a drag-gesture in this area now can trigger the drawer.

[image: maps with drawer]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject on your map styles.
Doing this will resolve your issue

```html
const React = require("react-native");

const { StyleSheet, Dimensions } = React;
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
export default {

  map: {
    width: width,
    height: height
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate ToggleDrawer() when you hit the side of the map which is covered by a thin TouchableOpacity window. here is the example code in homeview. make sure to bring in props as a variable to your function.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';

const HomeScreen = (props) => {

    
    
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style = {{flex: 1}}>
            <View style = {styles.container}>
            <MapView
          style={styles.mapStyle}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
            }
          />
        </MapView>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.mapDrawerOverlay} onPress = {() => {
                    props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();}
         } />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
    mapDrawerOverlay:{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        opacity: 0.0,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        width:10,

    },
    mapStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    },
  });
```